# Play UILocalNotification sound when app is in background and Do not distrub is on

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Hi I am trying to play local notification sound in iPhone when application is in background mode and
In settings app
    1. Do not disturb is on.
    2. Silence set to always.

because some other application achieve this e.g. Smart Alarm

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/smart-alarm-clock-sleep-cycles/id586910133?mt=8

Comment: since you are using local notification, just read the current time, and if its after a certain time lets say 10pm  or 8AM do not play sound. but check this library if you look on the source code I'm sure you will find your way out. https://github.com/indragiek/NSUserNotificationPrivate